# Seeking help with Extended events behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

I'm using Extended Events to track the procedures that are being executed on the server, along with the Hostname of its executor.

I've used the following XE script for the same:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [EXEC_SP] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed
(
  SET collect_statement=(0)
  ACTION
  (
    sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,
    sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.server_instance_name,
    sqlserver.server_principal_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,
    sqlserver.transaction_id,sqlserver.username
  )
  WHERE ( [sqlserver].[is_system]=(0))
)
 ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
 (
   SET FILENAME = N'C:\EXEC_SP.xel',
   METADATAFILE = N'C:\EXEC_SP.xem'
 )
 WITH
 (
   MAX_MEMORY=4096KB,
   EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=NO_EVENT_LOSS,
   MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=15 SECONDS,
   TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON
 );
```

However, every statement inside the body of the procedure being executed constitutes a row at the target.

For instance, if the body of my procedure has 5 statements in it, the event will be fired 5 times, and there will be 5 different entries corresponding to the same at the target.

I seek just a single entry for every procedure being executed instead of multiple entries.

That is every procedure being executed should constitute just 1 row instead of multiple.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sp_statement_completed` is doing exactly what you are asking it to : fire for every statement in a procedure.

You likely want to change that to `sqlserver.module_end` - but some other things in your session don't seem to match what you're after anyway, like `transaction_id`, when would instance name ever be different, and capturing both `database_id` and `database_name` is kind of redundant (unless you are dropping and re-creating databases constantly, you can derive one from the other, but I would argue that database name is more useful). Perhaps:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [EXEC_SP] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_end
(
  SET collect_statement=(0)
  ACTION
  (
    sqlserver.client_hostname,
    sqlserver.database_name,
    sqlserver.nt_username,
    sqlserver.server_principal_name,
    sqlserver.session_id,
    sqlserver.sql_text,
    sqlserver.username
  )
  WHERE ( [sqlserver].[is_system]=(0))
)
 ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
 (
   SET FILENAME = N'C:\EXEC_SP.xel',
   METADATAFILE = N'C:\EXEC_SP.xem'
 )
 WITH
 (
   MAX_MEMORY = 4096KB,
   EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = NO_EVENT_LOSS,
   MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 15 SECONDS,
   TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
   STARTUP_STATE = ON
 );
```

Comment: I merely want to track the name of the procedures that're being executed, and the hostnames that are executing them.
 So far I've garnered `module_end` event gets fired on the completion of a procedure. Are there any other cases where it is likely to be fired? 
 Also, at the target a great many rows exist for which the `sql_text` column simply does not exist. Is there a way to filter them out?
Some rows have `sql_text` column as NULL too

Comment: @Ritesh I don't think you want to filter out rows where sql_text wasn't collected. It is still an event for a stored procedure firing (you could also turn on `collect_statement=(1)`). You should still be able to get the procedure name anyway using `ObjectName = xmlEvent.value(N'(/event/data[@name="object_name"]/value)[1]', N'nvarchar(128)')`.

Comment: A great many system procedure executions are also being tracked, even though the predicate has been explicitly set to disallow so i.e. [sqlserver].[is_system]=(0). What's the reason for this?

Comment: `sqlserver.is_system` is checking whether the process is a system process, not whether the user is executing a system procedure. If users are executing `sp_help` or Management Studio executes `sp_helptext`, and you don't want to see those rows in the output, you'll need to filter them out by joining the output to `sys.all_objects` and filtering on `WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0`. I don't know that there's any way to filter them out up front.